# How to select all fields in a queryDef?

Tags: adobe, campaign-monitor

I want to select all fields in the recipients instead of selecting one by one

```html
 var query = xtk.queryDef.create(
  <queryDef schema="nms:recipient" operation="getIfExists">
    <select>
      <node expr="[@firstName]"/>
      <node expr="[@lastName]"/>
      <node expr="[@middleName]"/>
      <node expr="[@email]"/>

    </select>
    <where>
      <condition expr={"@Id='93975738'"}/>
      <condition expr={"@company='xxxx'"}/>
    </where>
  </queryDef>)
  var result = query.ExecuteQuery();
  logInfo(result.toXMLString());
```

Answer (score 4):

After figuring it from Adobe Campaign Javascript API:

```html
 var query = xtk.queryDef.create(
  <queryDef schema="nms:recipient" operation="select">
    <where>
      <condition expr={"@laId='93975738'"}/>
      <condition expr={"@company='SERE'"}/>
    </where>
  </queryDef>)
  query.SelectAll(false)
  var result = query.ExecuteQuery();
  logInfo(result.toXMLString());
```

Apparently queryDef.SelectAll(bolean duplicates) does it!